# Подбирать цвет в зависимости от картинки

Tags: android, java, bitmap

Как можно подбирать цвет в зависимости от картинки, как это сделано на панели задач при наведении в windows 7?

Требуется менять фон в зависимости от картинки в android.

Comment: [`Palette`][1].

  [1]: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html

Comment: @falstaf, вот ещё бы с минимальным примером...

Comment: а гугл сломался? ;)
сейчас сделаю пример

Comment: @Andreich, лениво мне гуглить... Да и тут, вроде, приветствуются минимальные примеры... =) Даже в шаблонных комментах есть такой призыв)

Comment: пример кода https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/20/palette-v21/
тут пример какие типы какие цвета выдают http://www.willowtreeapps.com/blog/palette-the-new-api-for-android/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Palette](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html)

Выбранные цвета они называют вибрирующими(т.е. яркий цвет, выделенный из изображения)

**Вибрирующий.** Palette.getVibrantSwatch()

**Вибрирующий темный.** Palette.getDarkVibrantSwatch()

**Вибрирующий светлый.** Palette.getLightVibrantSwatch()

**Заглушенный.** Palette.getMutedSwatch()

**Заглушенный темный.** Palette.getDarkMutedSwatch()

**Заглушенный светлый.** Palette.getLightMutedSwatch()

Есть 2 способа получения цвета - синхронный и асинхронный.

**Синхронный**

```
// Synchronous methods.
// --------------------------------
// These should be used when you have access to the underlying image loading thread.
// Picasso allows this through a Transformation. For other libraries, YMMV.

// Uses the default palette size (16).
Palette p = Palette.generate(bitmap);

// Allows you to specify the maximum palette size, in this case 24.

Palette p = Palette.generate(bitmap, 24);
```

**Асинхронный**

```
// Asynchronous methods
// --------------------------------
// This is the quick and easy integration path. Internally uses an AsyncTask so 
// this may not be optimal (since you're dipping in and out of threads)

// Uses the default palette size (16).
Palette.generateAsync(bitmap, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
       // Here's your generated palette
    }
});

// Allows you to specify the maximum palette size, in this case 24.
Palette.generateAsync(bitmap, 24, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
       // Here's your generated palette
    }
});
```

И еще нужно учесть, что класс не всегда может найти вибрирующий или заглушенный цвет. Все зависит от изображений и от размера палитры.

Класс доступен для Android >=21.

**UPD**
Если использовать Support Library, то класс можно использовать для Android >=7
[Support library palette](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-palette)

Подробнее [тут](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/20/palette-v21/).

Comment: > Класс доступен для Android >=21.

На самом деле, для API >= 7.

Comment:     я делаю так
    Palette palette = Palette.generate(bm);
    int color = palette.getDarkVibrantColor(0);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(color);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(color);

а для чего асинхронный режим выбора цвета

Comment: это ведь не простая  операция 2 + 2

Comment: @eldqs в главном потоке может тормозить на слабых телефонах.